# Customized CreateModelMixin - Object creation defined in my Model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My rest api view defines only two methods:

```
class RequestSerializerViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                    mixins.ListModelMixin,
                    viewsets.GenericViewSet):
```

i have some experience overwriting the list, but i have no experience overwriting create as it seems to be a lot more complicated.

What i want to achieve is following. My **Request** model has a special method which creates instance of Requests - **start_request**. This method creates not only the instance of **Request**, but also some additional foreign objects and assings them to the newly created **Request**.

So my goal would be to modify rest api **POST** (create, perform_create, or serializer - i have no idea atm. which is the correct way) method so, that it does not create the **Request** on its own, instead, uses **start_request** method of the model.
What would be the best django approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine `create` method in your Serializer. Let's assume you have `RequestSerializer`:

```
class RequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Request
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        request = Request.start_request(**validated_data)  # pass all parameters from serializer
        return request
```